# Getting 403 forbidden error when sending image data as base64 data in webservice made in Lumen

Tags: php, base64, php-7.3

Here is a basic structure of my code-

```
public function updateProfilePic(Request $request) {
        $response_object_name = 'update_profile_pic';
        $Validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
                [
                    'user_id'               => 'required',
                    'calender_id'           => 'required',
                    'profile_pic'           => 'required'
                ]
        );
        if($Validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([$response_object_name => $this->showValidationError($Validator->errors())]);
        } else {

            /*==============================profile picture customization=============================*/
            $path                   = '';
            $public_path            = env('PUBLIC_PATH', base_path('public')) . ($path ? '/' . $path : $path);
            $data                   = $request->profile_pic;                
            $startpos               = strpos($data, '/')+1;
            $posend                 = strpos($data, ';');
            $type                   = substr($data, $startpos, $posend-$startpos);     
            echo            $type; die();
            $new_profile_pic_name   = time() . mt_rand(). '.'.$type;
            $profile_pic_path       = $public_path . '/uploads/user_profile_image/';

            -----------------------------------------------------------
            -----------------------------------------------------------
       }
}
```

I am hitting the service through POSTMAN app. The profile_pic data is a base64 image data. Whenever I am sending any base64 data in profile_pic parameter, I am getting a 403 status. However, if I am sending any arbitrary string in the profile_pic parameter, I am not getting any 403 error (there are other error though because it is not a definite base64 code).

In server, PHP version is 7.3.

How can I solve this? What is the issue?

Comment: Have you checked the error log, if that has anything specific to say about this?

Comment: This might be some sort of firewall or similar on the server, that blocks this kind of data, because it thinks it might be used for an attack of some sort.

Comment: @CBroe, the error log file isn't getting updated at all.